# How to split a nested list into separate lists?

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list as follows

```
[['Norm,Macdonald', '61', '459000'], ['Paul,McCartney', '79', '2789000'], ['Samuel,Hui', '73', '538000']]
```

For the desired output it would be something like

```
[['Norm', 'Macdonald', '61', '459000'], ['Paul', 'McCartney', '79', '2789000'], ['Samuel', 'Hui', '73', '538000']]
```

How should I split it to make it look like this?

I have tried using .split(',') but it will return a nested list within the original list position i.e.

```
[[['Norm', 'Macdonald'], '61', '459000'], [['Paul', 'McCartney'], '79', '2789000'], [['Samuel', 'Hui'], '73', '538000']]
```

Comment: will you always get the data in same format ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the title is misleading/incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is:

```
l = [['Norm,Macdonald', '61', '459000'], ['Paul,McCartney', '79', '2789000'], ['Samuel,Hui', '73', '538000']]
new_l = [[*x[0].split(","), *x[1:]] for x in l]
print(new_l)
```

This will print

```
[['Norm', 'Macdonald', '61', '459000'], ['Paul', 'McCartney', '79', '2789000'], ['Samuel', 'Hui', '73', '538000']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
my_list = [['Norm,Macdonald', '61', '459000'], ['Paul,McCartney', '79', '2789000'], ['Samuel,Hui', '73', '538000']]

new_list = []
for l in my_list:
    temp = []
    for e in l:
        temp.extend(e.split(","))
    new_list.append(temp)
new_list
```

Another way:

```
new_list = [[s for s in item[0].split(',')] + item[1:] for item in my_list]
```

Result:

```
[['Norm', 'Macdonald', '61', '459000'],
 ['Paul', 'McCartney', '79', '2789000'],
 ['Samuel', 'Hui', '73', '538000']]
```

Answer (score 0):

using `join` and `split`

```
my_list = [['Norm,Macdonald', '61', '459000'], ['Paul,McCartney', '79', '2789000'], ['Samuel,Hui', '73', '538000']]
solution = [','.join(i).split(',') for i in my_list]
print(solution)
# output -> [['Norm', 'Macdonald', '61', '459000'], ['Paul', 'McCartney', '79', '2789000'], ['Samuel', 'Hui', '73', '538000']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with split

```
new_list = [[item for el in sub for item in el.split(',')] for sub in your_list]
print(new_list )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `','.join(the_list)` and `split(',')` together as in the first function.

the second function runs the first function for each list in your nested list and substitutes the internal lists with their unpacked versions.

```
def split_all_by(the_list, char):
    joined = char.join(the_list)
    splitted = joined.split(char)
    return splitted


def split_internal_lists_by(the_nested_list, char):
    for index in range(len(the_nested_list)):
        internal_list = the_nested_list[index]
        the_nested_list[index] = split_all_by(internal_list, ',')
    
    return the_nested_list


nested_list = [['Norm,Macdonald', '61', '459000'], ['Paul,McCartney', '79', '2789000'], ['Samuel,Hui', '73', '538000']]
result = split_internal_lists_by(nested_list, ',')
print(result)
```